# How can I upload a file that has spaces is its name with curl + php?

Tags: php, curl

I'm using this code for uploading a file to my server, using HTTP POST:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
$post = array(
    "upload" => '@' . $filepath
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$curl_result = curl_exec($ch);
```

This code works when $filepath does not contain spaces. However, it is possible that it might. When I test a path with spaces, I get the curl error "failed creating formpost data".

The curl manual does not tell me what to do, all it gives me are unix filenames without spaces. I tried following http://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2006-01/0079.html like so, but it didn't help me either:

```
"upload" => '"@' . $filepath . '"'
"upload" => '@"' . $filepath . '"'
```

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Rename the file so it has no spaces in the filename?! Is this an option :-)?

Comment: Sorry, no, the path could also contain spaces, and i don't know if i'll have a /tmp folder on the server this script will be put.. (to make a local copy) :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current versions of cURL (and PHP-cURL) handle spaces in filenames with no problems. Older versions may have had bugs, I'm not sure. Check you're using reasonably recent versions.

I can confirm spaces in filenames are no problem at all under PHP 5.2.13 and libcurl/7.19.4 on Linux.

The error message you're getting is the same one as when PHP/cURL can't find a file. Odds are the problems are somewhere else in your code. Probably an issue of having under- or over-escaped the spaces in the filename but probably not an issue with cURL itself.

I'd suggest looking elsewhere in your code for the problem or producing a hard-coded example of the problem occurring (where $filename is being set in the PHP directly rather than read from elsewhere).

Comment: I'm on PHP Version 5.2.9-2 (windows) with libcurl/7.19.4 OpenSSL/0.9.8k zlib/1.2.3, so i would expect it to work too. I tried setting the file hardcoded, but it didn't help..

Comment: Update: i output this: echo "file: " . (file_exists(realpath($filepath)) ? 'yes' : 'no'); and get "no".. However, i can open the file just fine when i copy paste the path in Explorer.. Mysterious!

Comment: Okay.. fixed. I was trying to upload a file from "c:\users\my user name". PHP has no right to enter that folder.. so yes, with "c:\temp\path with spaces\" it does work!

Answer (score 1):

You need the [realpath](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php)

```
$filepath = 'D:\7 habits copy.txt';
$url = 'http://www.speedyshare.com/upload.php?'.rand(10000000, 99999999);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
$post = array(
    "upload" => '@' . realpath($filepath)
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$curl_result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $curl_result;
```

Worked even on Windows. I'm pretty sure it will work on *NIX systems

Comment: realpath made no difference, unfortunately :(

Comment: what is your curl_errno($ch) ? Place it after curl_exec sentence.

Comment: The error is 26: CURLE_READ_ERROR (26) 

There was a problem reading a local file or an error returned by the read callback. 

Probably related to php not being able to find the file as well (see other answer)..

Comment: @Tominator Maybe your web user simply don't have enough privileges to read file you've chosen to upload w/ curl?

Comment: @Tominator, could you provide output of var_export(realpath($filepath));

Comment: Fixed.. php did not have the right to access the folder.. I didn't give you the answer flag because realpath didn't really make a difference (it's not a relative path anyway), but thanks for the help!

Comment: @Tominator Nothing to be sorry about ;)

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and I couldn't upgrade CURL on the system.

So I wrote a simple *escape* function that iterated on the string to replace the space character for the `+` sign, which is the traditional way to represent URLs with spaces.

For my surprise, it worked. :)

**C++** code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

std::string s = "";
std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), ' ', '+');
```

Answer (score -1):

You will need to escape the spaces. Not sure of the syntax you would use but maybe something like this:

```
'This is the file name with spaces.txt'
```

to

```
'This\ is\ the\ file\ name\ with\ spaces.txt'
```

again I'm not sure of the syntax it's just an example

or you might just need to add quotes to the file name, like this:

```
'This is the file name with spaces.txt'
```

Comment: No, i'm sorry, all of these strategies fail :(

Answer (score -1):

Put the target file in a variable, such as 'while read', and pass the variable in the curl the command. Be sure the variable is in double quotes and curl will handle it.

For example:

```
curl -T /PATH/TO/YOUR/FILE/DIRECTORY/"$f"
```

Comment: My answer is correct. I don't get why it is showing -1. Tripp Kinetics arbitrarily down voting? anyone can easily prove my answer works.